# Find the highest product of three numbers in a list (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, complexity

I wrote the below as a solution to:

#### Problem

Find the highest product of three numbers in a list

#### Constraints

- Is the input a list of integers?

  - Yes
- Can we get negative inputs?

  - Yes
- Can there be duplicate entries in the input?

  - Yes
- Will there always be at least three integers?

  - No
- Can we assume the inputs are valid?

  - No, check for None input
- Can we assume this fits memory?

  - Yes

#### Solution

```
from functools import reduce
from typing import List, Set, Callable

class Solution(object):

    def max_prod_three(self, array: List[int]) -> int:
        if array is None:
            raise TypeError("array cannot be None")
        if len(array) < 3:
            raise ValueError("array must have at least 3 elements")
        pos: List[int] = [n for n in array if n >= 0]
        neg: List[int] = [n for n in array if n < 0]
        pos_len: int = len(pos)
        neg_len: int = len(neg)

        candidates: Set[int] = set()
        mult: Callable[[int, int], int] = lambda x,y:x*y

        # possible combinations are:
        # ---, --+, -+-, +--, -++, +-+, ++-, +++
        # but order does not matter, so left with:
        # --- -> -  : len(neg) >= 3, will never be the max if len(pos) > = 3, if len(pos) < 3,
        #                            max will be with 3 lowest absolute values
        # --+ -> +  : len(neg) >= 2, len(pos) >= 1, will be the max if  exists -- > any ++
        # -++ -> -  : len(neg) >= 1, len(pos) >= 2, will never be the max if len(pos >= 3,
        #                            if len(pos) == 2, max will be with lowest absolute value
        # +++ -> +  : len(pos) >= 3, max is with 3 highest values

        if neg_len >= 3 and pos_len < 3:
            candidates.add(reduce(mult, sorted(neg)[-3:]))
        if neg_len >= 2 and pos_len >= 1:
            candidates.add(reduce(mult, sorted(neg)[:2] + [max(pos)]))
        if neg_len >= 1 and pos_len == 2:
            candidates.add(reduce(mult, sorted(neg)[-1:] + pos))
        if pos_len >= 3:
            candidates.add(reduce(mult, sorted(pos)[-3:]))
        
        return max(candidates)
```

Please could I get some feedback on it? In particular:

- Readability and does the comment make it clear what the code is doing?
- Pythonic-ness
- Typing - I have not really used typing before. Is using it on every variable worth doing, or overkill? If you know of a good resource to help a beginner, please add a link, thanks :)
- Complexity - how would I calculate this in big-0 notation? The provided solution [here](https://github.com/donnemartin/interactive-coding-challenges/blob/master/online_judges/prod_three/prod_three_solution.ipynb) is O(n) for time and O(1) space, but this runs much faster than that (~10x faster for list of 7,000 entries, ~2x faster for very small lists). Notice I loop over the array twice (to separate -ve and +ve numbers), while the solution given only loops over it once, but with quite a few min/max ops within that loop. As I understand it, my code is also O(n) (since O(2n) == O(n)). But if that is correct, how is the time taken so different?
- Lastly, this is not written to be production code of course. But, what would/could I add to it for some hypothetical production use case?

Comment: Just to make the last question clearer, I am asking "If this were production code, what should or could I add that is currently missing?"

Comment: `sorted()` is \$O(nlog(n))\$, so is your code. Try to sort each array once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding readability, I'd say typing variables makes them harder to read. As is:

```py
mult = lambda x, y: x * y
```

I can already tell its a function with two arguments that returns their product. I think this just adds noise to that:

```py
mult: Callable[[int, int], int] = lambda x, y: x * y
```

Also, these lines are kind of hard to read (there is a lot going on in each line, plus they have duplicated code):

```py
candidates: Set[int] = set()
mult: Callable[[int, int], int] = lambda x,y:x*y

if neg_len >= 3 and pos_len < 3:
    candidates.add(reduce(mult, sorted(neg)[-3:]))
if neg_len >= 2 and pos_len >= 1:
    candidates.add(reduce(mult, sorted(neg)[:2] + [max(pos)]))
if neg_len >= 1 and pos_len == 2:
    candidates.add(reduce(mult, sorted(neg)[-1:] + pos))
if pos_len >= 3:
    candidates.add(reduce(mult, sorted(pos)[-3:]))

return max(candidates)
```

You could change them to something like:

```py
candidates_groups = []

if neg_len >= 3 and pos_len < 3:
    candidates_groups.add(sorted(neg)[-3:])

if neg_len >= 2 and pos_len >= 1:
    candidates_groups.add(sorted(neg)[:2] + [max(pos)])

if neg_len >= 1 and pos_len == 2:
    candidates_groups.add(sorted(neg)[-1:] + pos)

if pos_len >= 3:
    candidates_groups.add(sorted(pos)[-3:])

# reduce is cool, but this is more readable
candidates = [cand[0] * cand[1] * cand[2] for cand in candidates_groups]

return max(candidates)
```

Then regarding your answer's Big-O notation, as @Pavlo Slavynsky said, sorting a list is already ***O(nlog(n))***, so that is your codes time complexity. Regarding space complexity, you store all of the values in the input in a new list, so that would make it ***O(n)***.

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

1. Why is your `max_prod_three` function in a class at all? It seems to me like it would be fine in the global namespace.
2. Why write your own `mult` function when you can just import `mul` from the `operator` module in the standard library?
3. I agree with @m-alorda on the type hints being a bit overkill. I'm a big fan of type hints, but they do make the code less legible, and a lot of yours are unnecessary. Type hints are only useful when they tell IDEs and/or other programmers things about your code that wouldn't otherwise be obvious. A call to `len()` is never going to return a value that isn't an integer, and any IDE or python programmer worth its/their salt will know that. So annotating the return value of a call to `len()` as being an integer doesn't add any non-obvious information to the code, and just clutters it up a little.

Comment: This was an answer to a code challenge. It already provided the Solution class and function signature - just like on Leetcode.
Good point about the mul operator, thanks! Also good advice on the type hints - seems restricting them to function args and return type is best, with occasional use where they clarify something not obvious is best.